# How to supress error messages from PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, parsing, phantomjs

I parse some html pages with many javascript inside using Phantomjs, but in the final output I see many Reference error and other JS error messages. They spoil my formatted html output. Since I get needed output inspite that some JS actually don't work I just want to suppress any error messages from the final page.

I'm not sure that these messages are originated from PhantomJS, but PHP output just before putting to the browser is absolutely clear from errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just set an empty function as the callback for the `page.onError` handler. [From the docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html):

> This callback is invoked when there is a JavaScript execution error not caught by a page.onError handler. This is the closest it gets to having a global error handler in PhantomJS, and so it is a best practice to set this onError handler up in order to catch any unexpected problems.

If you simply want to silence them, this should work:

```
page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, iainn.
I'm slightly confused because I've always tried (now do not remember exactly) similar expression with empty body but with no result. Probably, I applied wrong syntax.